# Horizontal cut on a cylinder with edge + displacement

Tags: faces

I am trying to get the effect (disco ball-ify it)I applied on the sphere with the cylinder, but it doesn't work. It extrudes just the vertical parts.
For both: mark sharp, sharp edge, displace. It works perfectly with the sphere but not with the cylinder. Can you help?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see both images, strange. Btw, I have the horizontal cuts on the cylinder as well as the vertical ones in edit mode but they (the horizontals) don't show up when I apply edge modifier + displace. Thanks

Comment: The displace acts in the direction of the faces' normals.  Because all of a cylinder's column's faces have the same normal, they all get displaced in the same direction, and so don't get disconnected from each other.  If you want to just make a gap, consider using a smooth modifier instead of the displacement modifier.  This will shrink each face's vertices toward each other.

Comment: Nathan thank you so much! It worked perfectly!